# Getting an API generated in-person signing envelope tracked through Salesforce Connect

Tags: json, salesforce, docusignapi

I'm using the rest API to create an in person signing session from salesforce. My envelope creation json is like this:

```
{
    "documents": [{
            "documentBase64": "'+base64EncodedDocToSign+'",
            "documentId": "1",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "name": "contract.pdf"
        }
    ],
    "emailSubject": "Please Sign",
    "recipients": {
        "inPersonSigners": [{
                "email": "some@gsome.com",
                "name": "Luis",
                "hostEmail": "some@gsome.com",
                "hostName": "Luis",
                "signerEmail": "other@gother.com",
                "signerName": "Charles",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [{
                            "anchorString": "s1",
                            "anchorXOffset": "0",
                            "anchorYOffset": "0",
                            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
                            "anchorUnits": "inches"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "clientUserId": "1000",
                "embeddedRecipientStartURL": "SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN",
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": "sent"
}
```

The next step would be for the object to be tracked using Connect. Connect is properly configured for the object and works if I "Sign with Docusign" or use a custom button.

I understand I must change the json to include the DSFSSourceObjectId custom field, with value equal to the Id of the object that is originating the request, but if I try to get a customField in there the json is not properly formatted anymore.

I tried adding the customField like:

```
...
            }
        ]
    },
    "customFields": [
        {
            "Name": "DSFSSourceObjectId",
            "Value": "' + objectId + '"
        }
    ],
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Is this viable?

Comment: Can you please post the json that you are referring to as not properly formatted.

Comment: @CodingDawg Also tried:  
   `"customFields": {
        "textCustomFields": [
             {
                 "configurationType": "salesforce",
                 "fieldId": "SalesforceSource",
                 "name": "DSFSSourceObjectId",
                 "required": "true",
                 "show": "false",
                 "value": "' + recipient.getObjectId() + '"
             }
         ]
    },`

To no avail

Answer (score 0):

I got this working adding the following to the JSON:

```
"customFields": {
    "textCustomFields": [{
            "value": "salesforceId",
            "required": "false",
            "show": "false",
            "name": "DSFSSourceObjectId"
        }
    ]
},
```